# WPF Overlay Outside Parent

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, overlay

I have the following example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfOverlayTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Width="600" Height="200" Background="LightBlue">
        <Grid Margin="0,125,0,0" Height="75" Width="200" Background="Red">
            <Grid Margin="0,75,0,0" Background="Black" Height="20" Width="200" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid  Grid.Row="1" Height="200" Width="600" Background="LightGreen" />
</Grid>
```

**How can I make the Black Grid being displayed?**

edit:
To make the Problem a bit more clear:
I Want to define the `Black Grid` **inside** the `Red Grid`, but it should be displayed **over** the `Green Grid`.
See the `Red Grid` as a `UserControl` and the `Black Grid` as a Menu Overlay.

Comment: Where do you want it to be displayed? Below red one? Why just not include it in LightGreen Grid then?

Comment: Yes below the Green one. Imagine the red grid is my UserControl and I want to display a "Menu Bar" as like the black grid.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I see questions and answers here that I just can't believe. If you want to put two or more elements into one `Grid.Row` or `Column`, then just set their `Grid.Row` values to the same value. The lower the element is defined in the XAML, the further in front the element will be in the UI. So to add the black `Grid` on top of the green `Grid`, you can just do this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Width="600" Height="200" Background="LightBlue">
        <Grid Margin="0,125,0,0" Height="75" Width="200" Background="Red">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="200" Width="600" Background="LightGreen" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Height="20" Width="200" /> <!-- This will be on top -->
</Grid>
```

[image]

### UPDATE

It's pretty difficult to work out what you actually want, but after reading the comments, it seems as though you might want this instead:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Width="600" Height="200" Background="LightBlue">
        <Grid Margin="0,125,0,0" Height="75" Width="200" Background="Red">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Width="200" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="200" Width="600" Background="LightGreen" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

This is basic `Grid` stuff. I recommend the material in the [Grid Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) page on MSDN.

### UPDATE 2

Now that you have provided a description of your problem in your question, I can finally provide the correct XAML for your requirements:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Width="600" Height="200" Background="LightBlue" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="200" Width="600" Background="LightGreen" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="75" Width="200" Background="Red">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- This will be on top -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Width="200" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Again: I want to define the Black Bar inside the Red Grid but render it over the the other controls outside. But thank you, I know how to define a Grid ;)

Comment: Firstly, why say 'Again'? You didn't provide that description before. Previously you said *below the Green one*, *I wanted to display the Black Bar over the green grid* and *I want to stay inside my red grid*, which are all different. Also, you then say *I know how to define a Grid*... but then if that were true, why on earth did you ask this question?

Comment: Please just see the comments. I want to define the black grid inside the red and make it as an overlay over the other controls. The question was not to redesign my Grid layout. The question was how to make the black bar visible.

Comment: Did I not make the black bar appear inside the red rectangle *and* make it overlay the other controls (green rectangle)? I did exactly as you requested. Is the black bar not visible? I don't understand your problem... I have done exactly what you suggested and still you say to *see the comments*?? Users shouldn't have to see the comments. It is your responsibility as the question author to clearly provide all of your requirements *in your question*. If this solution is not what you wanted, then please clearly explain exactly what you do want in your question.

Comment: Dude take my XAML Markup and show me how to display the Black Grid. Of course I know how to solve this problem, when I change the markup, but that's not what I want to.

Comment: You do realise that all of this confusion over what you *actually* want has been caused by the fact that you did not (and still have not) provided a clear and valid description of your requirements, don't you? That's the reason why I mentioned that fact in the first place. Your last comment is the very first time that you mentioned that you didn't want to change the markup... do you not think that that was a valid piece of information that you should share with the people that are trying to help you? And I still don't see your problem... just replace the coloured rectangles for your controls.

Comment: I agree with the meta-feedback that was originally in this post, but since answers are for many future readers, it is probably best for them to be excised. Trust that's OK!

Comment: No problem... :)

Answer (score 1):

Set a RowDefinition on your Red grid and assign the Black Grid to it

```
<Canvas>
    <Grid Width="600" Height="200" Background="LightBlue">
    </Grid>
    <Grid Margin="0,200,0,0" Height="175" Width="600" Background="LightGreen" />
    <Grid Margin="200,125,0,0" Height="100" Width="200" Background="Red">
        <Grid Margin="0,75,0,0" Background="Black" Height="20" Width="200" />
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

[image]

EDIT: Added a screenshot

EDIT: Switched to a Canvas

Comment: I wanted to display the Black Bar over the green grid :)

Comment: Oops, I thought you wanted to display the black bar like a MenuBar on the Red grid. So then @icebat asked the correct question, why not just add it to the green grid?

Comment: Because I want to stay inside my red grid. I mean im not playing with couloured Grids, this is just an exampel for a real applciation Problem ;) Imagine the Red Grid is a UserControl and the black bar is a menu displayed as an overlay when the usercontrol is selected.

Comment: I don't believe you can do it using a Grid. I switched the primary container to a Canvas which allows you to overlay controls on each other. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Vinny, you are mistaken. Please see my answer for the correct solution.

Comment: @Sheridan Excellent solution! I was unaware of that. Thanks.